# How to add condition on multiple-join table

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have those two tables:

```
client:
  id (int) #PK
  name (varchar)

client_category:
  id (int) #PK
  client_id (int)
  category (int)
```

Let's say I have those datas:

```
client: {(1, "JP"), (2, "Simon")}
client_category: {(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (4,2,2)}
```

**tl;dr** *client #1* has category 1, 2, 3 and *client #2* has only category 2

I am trying to build a query that would allow me to search multiple categories. For example, I would like to search every clients that has *at least* category 1 and 2 (would return client #1). How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select client.id, client.name
from client
inner join client_category cat1 on client.id = cat1.client_id and cat1.category = 1
inner join client_category cat2 on client.id = cat2.client_id and cat2.category = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This would do the trick

```
SELECT
  c.id, 
  c.name
FROM
  client c 
  INNER JOIN client_category cc on c.id = cc.client_id
WHERE
  cc.category in (1,2)
GROUP BY 
  c.id, c.name
HAVING
  count(c.id) >= 2
```

***[update]***

`count(c.id)` should be `count( DISTINCT c.id )` if a category is allowed to be selected for the same client more than once, as OMG Ponies noted in his comment.

Comment: Needs to be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) >= 2`, otherwise if there were a client with two associations to category 1 - this would be a false positive. Assuming the data model allows such a thing to happen (probably shouldn't).

Comment: @OMG, i assumed a logical model :) but you are correct. That would be the all-encompassing choice..

Answer (score 0):

the "dumb" answer

```
select c.id
  from client c
 where c.id in (select cc.client_id from client_category cc where cc.id = 1)
   and c.id in (select cc.client_id from client_category cc where cc.id = 2)
```

Comment: the dumb answer to a dumb question, I know. Should've thought of that.